# PHP socket programming: Unique resource id for a client and check client online

Tags: php, android, sockets, socket.io, tcp

I am new to socket programming. I am assigned to develop PHP socket server to communicate with multiple client( android application).

I am using Ratchet- http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world to develop the socket.

1)When I connect a client, server assign a resource id to connection. I can send data to client using that resource id. But after I disconnect and connect again it assign different resource id to that connection. Is it possible to  use same resource id  each time same client reconnect?

2)if the client disconnect the connection, i can get it from onClose function method

```
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
    $this->clients->detach($conn);
    echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
}

public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) { 
    echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n"; 
    $conn->close();
}
```

When the onError method will be called?

3) If the connection loss from client end due to internet problem,  How can server know it? My idea is to send some echo data each 30 second from server to each client. if client did't response data back, it means connection loss. is there is any other way?

Please help me on my questions

Thanks